# SQLMX/IBM-liberty-datasource: Valid jdbc driver not found

Tags: websphere-liberty, hp-nonstop

I'm getting the below `jdbc driver not found error`, though I've included `t4sqlmx-3.3.jar` in `<liberty_server>/lib folder`. What additional changes are required?

```
<library id="sqlmx-lib">
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="t4sqlmx-3.3.jar"/>
</library>
```

Error :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: DSRA4000E: A valid JDBC driver implementation class was not found for the jdbcDriver dataSource[default-0]/jdbcDriver[default-0] using the library sqlmx-lib. []
    at com.ibm.ws.jdbc.internal.JDBCDriverService.classNotFound(JDBCDriverService.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.jdbc.internal.JDBCDriverService.createAnyDataSource(JDBCDriverService.java:368)
    at com.ibm.ws.jdbc.DataSourceService.init(DataSourceService.java:592)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.AbstractConnectionFactoryService$2.run(AbstractConnectionFactoryService.java:460)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.AbstractConnectionFactoryService$2.run(AbstractConnectionFactoryService.java:457)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.AbstractConnectionFactoryService.initPrivileged(AbstractConnectionFactoryService.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.AbstractConnectionFactoryService.createResource(AbstractConnectionFactoryService.java:144)
    at com.ibm.ws.resource.internal.ResourceFactoryTrackerData$1.getService(ResourceFactoryTrackerData.java:120)
    ... 107 more
```

After datasource fix, some sqlmx specific error:

```
[12/05/18 14:39:26:473 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Pool requests blocked for dataSource[default-0]/connectionManager, connection pool is being shut down.
[12/05/18 14:39:26:473 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:822)
[12/05/18 14:39:26:473 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:152)
[12/05/18 14:39:26:474 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:116)
[12/05/18 14:39:26:474 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R  at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:92)
[12/05/18 14:39:26:474 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R  at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
[12/05/18 14:39:26:474 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R  ... 95 more
[12/05/18 14:39:26:474 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Pool requests blocked for dataSource[default-0]/connectionManager, connection pool is being shut down.
[12/05/18 14:39:26:475 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:1275)
[12/05/18 14:39:26:475 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:573)
[12/05/18 14:39:26:475 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:309)
[12/05/18 14:39:26:475 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:143)
[12/05/18 14:39:26:475 EDT] 000003f8 SystemErr           R  ... 98 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, it appears that you have configured a `<dataSource>` element in your server.xml, but not included it in your question.  Using the `<library>` configuration you did provide, your configuration might look like this:

```
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/myDB" type="javax.sql.XADataSource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="sqlmx-lib"  javax.sql.XADataSource="com.tandem.t4jdbc.SQLMXDataSource"/>
    <properties databaseName="SAMPLEDB" hostName="localhost" port="12345"/>
</dataSource>
```

For more information on how to configure a DataSource in Liberty, see: 
[Configuring relational database connectivity in Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html)

**NOTE:** Based on googling for the SQL/MX JDBC driver documentation, I found that their XADataSource implementation class name is `com.tandem.t4jdbc.SQLMXDataSource`.  If that class name is not correct for your JDBC driver jar, then use whatever class your jar has.  Also, if your driver does not provide any implementation of `javax.sql.XADataSource`, then change the configuration to be `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` instead.